# How do I redirect in ReactJS in a navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying to redirect between pages in a navbar and I wondering on how to do that specific component.

Here is my code.

```
function redirectRegistration() {
  window.location = '../src/Registration.JS'
}

function redirectLogin() {
  window.location = '../src/App.js'
}

const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login');
const registerBtn = document.getElementById('registerPage');

loginBtn.addEventListener('click' , redirectLogin);
registerBtn.addEventListener('click' , redirectRegistration)
```

I am trying to know how to redirect from my login to my registration page.

Comment: Two questions: 1) are you using any routing API (i.e. React Router)? 2) Are you trying to achieve a hard navigation or a soft navigation (hard navigation meaning the entire page will be re-loaded when the URL changes)?

Comment: Check https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start. React router is the way to go.

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher it is the Javascript code I put to manipulate that specific component but this is how I redirect in javascript I am wondering how to do it in react

Comment: @ChristianSantos I am not using any routing API and it should be soft navigation to go from a login component to a register component

Comment: In that case, I agree with @croraf that React Router is the way to go unless you need to implement your own router for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, React has a virtual dom that isn't built around getting element ID's and then adding listeners to them. React components have a render method where you can put JSX (Basically HTML) where you can place event listener methods for the HTML that they are inside of.

Typically you would build button components inside of React and then add in an onClick method, which is the same as adding a click event listener. I'm honestly not sure if doucment.getElementByID works with React, but even if it does that is not the way that React is designed to be used and building in this fashion is going to give you problems down the line.

Second, in React you typically don't redirect with window.location unless you are redirecting to an outside location. Even so, you typically wrap that in a tag from React Router.  One advantage of React/SPA's is that you only have to refresh the parts of the page that have changed, and using window.location gets rid of that advantage.

React Router is typically the way that you would redirect in React, but that's also built around the usage of React Components instead of using getElementByID and then event Listeners.

Advice: Refactor your buttons into React Components, then use React Router for your redirect.

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing things the "React way". You can rewrite your functions using arrow syntax and can create your buttons using JSX in your render method. Try this:

```
    redirectRegistration = () => {
        window.location = '../src/Registration.JS'
    }

    redirectLogin = () => {
        window.location = '../src/App.js'
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <button id="login" onClick={this.redirectLogin}>Login</button>
            <button id="registerPage" onClick={this.redirectRegistration}>Register</button>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
  }
```